# Why does printing multiple zero width spaces print less than expected in C?

Tags: c, unicode, zero-width-space

The program below is supposed to print A, 100 zero width spaces or '0x200B' and then print B, but when I execute it, it prints 10 zero width spaces instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t space = 0x200B;

    wprintf(L"A");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        wprintf(L"%lc", space);
    }

    wprintf(L"B");
}
```

I count these by copy pasting the output from the bash terminal into a online char counter so there. Why does this happen if it happens to anyone else at all?

Comment: What operating system and terminal program are you using?  If you pipe output to a file using your Bash shell (i.e. `myprogram > file.txt`), is the file the correct size?

Comment: That was the solution thanks

Comment: Well, we didn't solve your original problem of why the online char counter gave the wrong number.  We just narrowed it down.  It's probably either a problem with the counter or your terminal program.  (Or possibly something weird your C libary does when writing to an interactive standard output pipe.)

Comment: We can rule out its the charcounter's fault, when I copy paste the output from a file to the counter it gives me the expected amount of characters